# Mixed model via ridge regression

Tags: mixed-model, ridge-regression, blup

A mixed model can be recast as a ridge regression for a specific regularization parameter $\lambda$ that penalizes only the random effects -- aka dummy variables for the grouping levels.

Fitting a model this way might be appealing if one desires to pick $\lambda$ based on cross-validation, rather than assuming that the maximum likelihood solution will predict well out of sample.

However, then you've got at least as many regression parameters as you do groups.  Is there a convenient way of recasting this ridge regression $\lambda$ into the variance of the random effects, with an equally-convenient way of getting the random-effect BLUPS?

Comment: (+1) (Years ago I would be able to give the answer a go but not nowadays.) I would be inclined to say "*no equally-convenient way*" exists because if it existed we would use already. I don't know if you have already seen this blog https://www.jld-stats.com/2018/12/21/comparing-a-mixed-model-with-a-ridge-regression/ which is relevant. Please note that this "ridge equivalence" works (conceptually at least) for "vanilla" random intercepts. As soon as we start having random slopes, cross-effects, etc. that paradigm becomes almost unintelligible.

Comment: @usεr11852 good link.  Perhaps like you, I'm also not the same as I was years ago.  I had forgotten what a PITA mixed model estimation is.  So, right, I'll probably just stick with ridge.  If my matrix gets too big to invert I'll just do backprop.  Why do you say that things get unintelligible with random slopes?  Just the difficulty in proving equivalence?  Or something practical in chugging along with an $X$ matrix that contains your groups interacted with your dummies?

Comment: I think both of the points you mentioned are valid. Also to a certain extent in the use case of random slopes only, we fit $M$ different $\lambda$s where $M$ is the number of sub-groups in our sample. If we assume some random slopes too and any other interactions we have to formulate the relevant error correlation matrices (compound symmetric, etc) based on the group-structure but how much now this formulation is "ridge-like" is very open to debate. Fun question!